# Issues with basic embedding of youtube_dl into a Python 3.4 script

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-dl

I have been tinkering with [youtube_dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) and have been having issues implementing it into my Python 3.4 script.

I am simply trying to create a variable that stores the output (adjusted with a few options.)

However, I can't seem to figure out how to add the options to the function and the output seems to only be printed no matter what I do (as opposed to be stored in my variable.)

Here is my current code:

```
class MyLogger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        pass

    def warning(self, msg):
        pass

    def error(self, msg):
        print(msg)

ydl_opts = {
'logger': MyLogger(),
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])
```

Which just downloads a test video currently. Here is the GitHub links that explain embedding youtube_dl:

- [Embedding youtube_dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#embedding-youtube-dl)
- [Embedding options](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L121-L269)

And here is the pseudo-code of what I am trying to do:

```
class MyLogger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        pass

    def warning(self, msg):
        pass

    def error(self, msg):
        print(msg)

ydl_opts = {
'logger': MyLogger(),
'InfoExtractors':[{'simulate','forceduration'}]
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    duration = ydl.download(['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])
print('The duration is {0}'.format(duration))
```

Does anyone have any advice or ideas? I have been stuck on this issue for longer than I would care to admit.

Comment: That doesn't look like pseudo-code; it looks like wishful Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `extract_info` method, it returns a dictionary [with the video info](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/5c5a3ecf1b5337510378b782a14525584769e6d6/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py#L64):

```
import youtube_dl

class MyLogger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        pass

    def warning(self, msg):
        pass

    def error(self, msg):
        print(msg)

ydl_opts = {
    'logger': MyLogger(),
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc', download=True)
print('The duration is {0}'.format(info['duration']))
```

Answer (score 1):

From a brief dive through the source of `youtube_dl`, it looks like what you want to do isn't possible without modifying `youtube_dl`. From [the source](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L1681):

```
def download(self, url_list):
    """Download a given list of URLs."""
    outtmpl = self.params.get('outtmpl', DEFAULT_OUTTMPL)
    if (len(url_list) > 1 and
            '%' not in outtmpl and
            self.params.get('max_downloads') != 1):
        raise SameFileError(outtmpl)

    for url in url_list:
        try:
            # It also downloads the videos
            res = self.extract_info(
                url, force_generic_extractor=self.params.get('force_generic_extractor', False))
        except UnavailableVideoError:
            self.report_error('unable to download video')
        except MaxDownloadsReached:
            self.to_screen('[info] Maximum number of downloaded files reached.')
            raise
        else:
            if self.params.get('dump_single_json', False):
                self.to_stdout(json.dumps(res))

    return self._download_retcode
```

As you can see, it calls `self.to_screen` and `self.to_stdout` with everything that's not the return code. You could possibly patch one of those functions to redirect the output, but I don't think it's possible otherwise.

If you do want to patch `self.to_screen`, you should be able to do something like this

**WARNING: THIS MAY BREAK THINGS**

```
def patched_to_screen(self, message, skip_eol=False):
    return message


def patch_to_stdout(self, message, skip_eol=False, check_quiet=False):
    return message


ydl = YoutubeDL()
ydl.to_screen = patched_to_screen
tdl.to_stdout = patched_to_stdout
```